# Regular Expression for extracting text between two strings

Tags: regex

I am trying to parse an html-like format to use within a C++ application. Here is the format:

```
< item1="1" item2="2" item3="3" ... />
```

The expression I have found to work is something like this:

```
((?<=item1=\").*?(?=\"))|((?<=item2=\").*?(?=\"))|((?<=item3=\").*?(?=\")) --- etc.
```

This successfully captures:

```
{1, 2, 3, ...}
```

While this may be extensive, I am a novice at best with regular expressions and this seems to do the trick. The problem I'm running into with this is that when the string is blank, as in "", the expression will capture from the ending quotation to the following beginning quotation as well. For example:

```
< item1="" item2="2" />
```

will be captured as:

```
{ , item2=, 2}
```

I would like to find a way to limit the capture group to only what's inside the quotations.

Thanks.

Edit 1: I also need to preserve the ability to have spaces and such within the quotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?<=\=\")[^\"]*
```

this one will works, you only need match all char not `"` after `="`

Comment: Thank you! I just added some literals to the lookbehind to allow it to capture items out of order still. `(?<=item2\=\")(?'item2')[^\"]*`

Comment: Correction to my addition: `(?'item'(?<=item\=\")[^\"]*)` to properly capture the named group.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is looking for any character `.`, which includes spaces. You'll want to change it to look for any non-whitespace char `\S` (which is PCRE, not sure if that is the engine C++ uses).

Comment: I might also add that I need to allow spaces within the quotations. I don't believe this solution would allow that.